# Split list into sublists based on a value of a certain property?

Tags: c#, list

I have a list of events, each of which has a datetime property. I need to split the list up into sublists by year. The trick is, my list of events is pulled from a database and subject to change, so I can't just hardcode the set of years and sort the events into the right year. Is there a way that I can split my main list of events into sublists so that within each sublist, each event has the same year? So I would end up with a sublist of all 2010 events, a sublist of all 2011 events, and so on.

My list is created like this :

```
foreach (var ev in eventResults)
    {
        eventsList.Add(new Event()
        {
            Name = ev.Title,
            Month = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetAbbreviatedMonthName(ev.StartDate.Month),
            Day = ev.StartDate.Day,
            Year = ev.StartDate.Year
        });
    }
```

Comment: GroupBy is what you are looking for:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7325278/group-by-in-linq

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You need to make a [grouping by](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/group-query-results) year like this:

```
eventsList.GroupBy(x => x.Year)
```

So later you will be able to iterate through result of code above:

```
foreach (var eventsInYear in eventsList.GroupBy(x => x.Year))
{
    // eventsInYear.Key - year
    // eventsInYear - collection of events in that year
}
```

Comment: This is incredibly useful.  Just fell in love with C# again.

Comment: After grouping, how would you make separate lists based on the year?

Comment: @KenGordon `GroupBy` returns `IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey,TSource>>`, since `IGrouping` implements `IEnumerable`, you can simply call `ToList` on each individual item. However I do not quite understand why you need that, the purpose of `IGrouping` is to provide a reference to a grouping key (Year). If you don't like `IGrouping` you could reorganise it into `IDictionary`. If you declare `var dict =             new Dictionary<int, IList<Event>>();` outside `foreach` loop, then you can populate it by calling `dict.Add(eventsInYear.Key, eventsInYear.ToList());`

Comment: @Vladimirs This is somewhat new to me and I wanted to see how to separate parts of a list into separate lists, such as if you wanted 3 lists containing three years. Does that make any more sense?

Comment: @Ken here you go `var year2000 = eventsList.GroupBy(x => x.Year).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == 2000).ToList();
var year2001 = eventsList.GroupBy(x => x.Year).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == 2001).ToList();
var year2002 = eventsList.GroupBy(x => x.Year).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == 2002).ToList();`

Comment: @Vladimirs Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 12):

Use GroupBy:

```
var eventsByYear = eventsList.GroupBy(a => a.Year);
```

You can then iterate through that collection to process each year:

```
foreach (var yearEvents in eventsByYear) 
{
    // yearEvents contains all the events for one particular year
    Console.WriteLine("Events for year: " + yearEvents.Key);
    foreach (var e in yearEvents) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: btw event is a keyword and you can't use it right-away, should be @event